# How do you plot the 3-D plot for pcolor style using one matrix with varying one variable along Z-axis?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I get `RFM` square matrix `size(64*64)` as function of `x` and `h` variable shown below. x = input signal consisting of(pX2),where `p` can be of any size and h = threshold value (1X1) for each `RFM`matrix respectively. `x` is same constant values for all varying `h`. let's say for example h will be in this range,`h = [0:0.2:1]`

> `RFM = function(x,h)`

- `x=rand(100X2)` and `h_1 = 0` then i will get  `RFM_1` of (64X64)  matrix.
- `x is same, x=rand(100X2)` and `h_2 = 0.3` then i will get  `RFM_2` of (64X64) matrix.
- `x is same, x=rand(100X2)` and `h_3=0.6` then i will get  `RFM_2` of (64X64) matrix

As of now i have plotted `RFM_1` in pcolor plot and also for each `RFM`value i have plotted with `pcolor`  plot.

**I want the 3d plot for the RFM matrix in `pcolor` style with varying function of the `h` in Z-axis. It should look for each `RFM` matrix plot is stacked one above the other? How can i do this in MATLAB?**

Expected output plot should somewhat look like below. Here,only one `RFM_1` with `h_1` matrix is plotted in this figure. I expect `RFM_2` matrix at `h_2=0.5` and so on plotted each with`pcolor` style. [image: ![enter image description here]

I have shared the required code here. You can use `test.m` file to check the above function. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0sYDrkkEHQ-b25GMlphUEFRcDA&usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

here's a way if I understand you correctly:

```
data=peaks(64); % fake data
t=-0:8; % some thersholds

tdata=bsxfun(@gt,data,permute(t,[3 1 2])); % 3d threshold
data3=repmat(data,[1 1 numel(t)]); %just copy data to the 3rd dim
A=data3.*tdata;
A(A==0)=NaN; % this will eliminate showing the zero values

% plottning
h=slice(A,[],[],1:numel(t));
set(h,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp');

alpha(0.5);
```

[image]

Comment: Thats not quite it. As you have shown linear relation( multiplication) to get 3dimensional data. I have updated my question with more clarity(I hope). Please do check it again and if possible let me know the solution. Thank you.